# Using angle between vectors to find identity of vector new rotated sixty degrees

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Gievn $\vec{u}=\binom{u_1}{u_2}$, if it is rotated sixty degrees anti-clockwise prove that the resulting vector will be $\vec{v}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{u_1-\sqrt{3}u_2}{\sqrt{3}u_1+u_2}$

I think there are better methods out there but one idea I had was to use $$\cos 60=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{\left|\vec{u}\right|\left|\vec{v}\right|}\:$$

and solve for $\vec{v}$ but obviously this seems impossible to me with the $|\vec{v}|$ and I see no where to force a $\sqrt{3}$ to appear.

Is this true? Or if this method works please share. I have other ideas which probably work but this one also came to mind but with no fruitition

Answer (score 2):

Your method actually could work but there is an easier approach involving the Rotation matrix which is defined as

$R_\theta =\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$

it can be easily proven that

$R_\theta \begin{pmatrix} \cos x\\ \sin x  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos (x+\theta)\\ \sin( x+\theta)  \end{pmatrix}$

Let $\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ u_2  \end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix} \cos x\\ \sin x  \end{pmatrix}$

since rotating sixty degrees anti-clockwise will result same as rotating three hundred clockwise let $\theta=300$

$R_\theta \begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ u_2  \end{pmatrix}=rR_\theta\begin{pmatrix} \cos x\\ \sin x  \end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix} \cos (x+300)\\ \sin( x+300)  \end{pmatrix}$

$r\begin{pmatrix} \cos (x+300)\\ \sin( x+300)  \end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix} \cos (x)\cos300-\sin x \sin300 \\ \sin x\cos300+\cos x\sin300  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{r}2\cos x-r\frac{\sqrt3\sin x}{2}\\ \frac{r}{2}\sin x +\frac{r\sqrt3}{2}\cos x  \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{u_1-\sqrt{3}u_2}{\sqrt{3}u_1+u_2}
$

Comment: Ah yes, this was the other method I was thinking of (didn't know it was called a "rotation matrix" though). Thanks for the answer!